# Program not proceeding after taking array input in C

Tags: arrays, c, input

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    int n,a[n],element;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the elements of array in ascending order\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter the element to be searched: ");
    scanf("%d", &element);
    int low = 0;
    int high = n-1;
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    int flag = 0;
    while(low<=high){
        if(a[mid]==element){
            flag =1;
            break;
        }
        if(a[mid]<element){
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            high = mid -1;
        }
    }
    if(flag){
        printf("%d found", element);
    }
    else{
        printf("Not found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I am only able to enter the elements of array and thus the program does not proceed further.
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the value of `n` in `a[n]` here `int n,a[n],element;`??

Comment: all are taken from the user

Comment: You don't get it. `int n;` creates `n` but it's value is indeterminate. You cannot use it until it has been assigned a value. But you do use it in `int n,a[n],element;` immediately after declaration and before it has been assigned a value in declaring `a[n]` ... Don't do `int a[n];` until **after** you read (and validate the conversion) of `n` with `scanf()`. In other words, the value of `n` must be set before you can do `int a[n];`

Comment: You also need to update `mid = (low+high)/2;` at the end of your loop each iteration... as `mid` will change after each iteration until the result is found.

Answer (score 2):

```
int n,a[n],element;
```

Is equivalent of saying

```
int n;
int a[n];
int element;
```

Notice something? You're declaring an array of variable size with an uninitialized variable `n`. This leads to unexpected behaviour. Declare your array **after** the value of n has been set!

---

```
int n,element;
scanf("%d", &n);
int a[n];
```

Comment: I'd go ahead and call it *Undefined Behavior*. Accessing the value of `n` (a variable with automatic storage duration) while its value is indeterminate -- good old UB. (yes, the results can be quite unexpected `:)`

Comment: declared the array after taking n from the user still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

On observing your code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    int n,a[n],element;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the elements of array in ascending order\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]); // correction: here you had given space after %d...
    }
    printf("Enter the element to be searched: ");
    scanf("%d", &element);
    int low = 0;
    int high = n-1;
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    int flag = 0;
    while(low<=high){
        if(a[mid]==element){
            flag =1;
            break;
        }
        if(a[mid]<element){
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            high = mid -1;
        }
    }
    if(flag){
        printf("%d found", element);
    }
    else{
        printf("Not found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you had given space `scanf("%d ", &a[i]);` after `%d` which should not be used, that's why your program is not proceeding after taking array input... I am assuming your binary search operation is correct and working fine...